# Java "error": "Not Found", "message": "No message available",

Tags: java, spring-boot, curl

I work with a small Spring app where I have few values in the database and I would like to retrieve them using the mutable call.

The API is here,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/products")
public class ProductAPI {

    private ProductService service;

    @Autowired
    public void setService(ProductService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }


@GetMapping("/stock/")
public ResponseEntity<Product> findById(@RequestParam("productId") String productId) {

    Product product = service.findById(productId).get();
    return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(product));
}

...........
}
```

The service call,

```
@Service
public class ProductService {


 private ProductRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public void setProductRepository(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    public Optional<Product> findById(String id) {

       return repository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

The repository class,

```
@Repository
 public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, String>{


 }
```

When I make the call using the cURL, I get the message,

```
   $ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/stock?productId=Product%20ID | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   142    0   142    0     0    845      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   850
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-25T12:19:31.797+0000",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/api/v1/products/stock"
}
```

I have the entries in the database inserted correctly. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have extra **/** in your mapping

```
@GetMapping("/stock/")
```

so if you want request like this

> curl -X GET
>   http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/stock/?productId=Product%20ID

you need mapping like:

```
@GetMapping("/stock")
```

in you current version right curl looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/stock/?productId=Product%20ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have clearly mentioned the mapping as @GetMapping("/stock/") in your controller,
and when you are trying to access the resource by the path /stock obviously there is no such mapping. Due to that, you are getting 404 found exception.

So, update the mapping like @GetMapping("/stock").

Happy Learning!

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the other answer as posted earlier.